# Network printer shows the print server name after mapping

Tags: windows, network-printer, print-server

when we are mapping our printers to our computers from a Windows print server the name of the printer shows the print server as well (see example below). Is there a way to omit the print server and map it with just the printer name?

Is this a setting on the print server side or is it something on the client side? I will appreciate any inputs!! Cheers!

Example:

Name showing up after mapping:
"Printer Name" on "Print Server"

Desired Outcome: "Printer Name"

I checked the printer settings after mapping, it just shows the correct printer name. I didn't see any settings to omit the print server section of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behavior.

The only way to bypass that is to use GPO per machine to deploy your printer.

- By the printer deployment GPO it will create a printer with a print queue that point the server name.
- By GPP you will have to create a TCP/IP printqueue on the remote computer, and it will check the print server printqueue for the settings to push.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That explains a lot.